# Richfaces 3.3 extendedDataTable onRowClick is setting data from previous row click

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have this datatable with an a4j:support tag so taht when someone clicks on a row, i want to display or hide certain buttons based on the status of the row selected.

The problem is that the data in my backing bean is always one click behind.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable
    id="formSummaryTableId"
    var="dataSummary"
    value="#{FormSearch.summaries}"
    binding="#{FormBacking.table}"
    selection="#{FormSearch.selection}"
    rowKeyVar="rkv"
    frozenColCount="0"
    sortMode="single" height="500px" width="795px"
    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" rowClasses="even, odd"
    selectedClass="itemSelected">

    <a4j:support event="onRowClick" actionListener="#{FormBacking.onClickForm}"
        reRender="DesignerForm:formEditToolbar" />
....
```

FormBacking.onClickForm

```
public void onClickForm(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Iterator<Object> selectionKeys = getFormSearch().getSelection().getKeys();
    LOG.info("selectionKeys = "+selectionKeys.hasNext());
    if (selectionKeys.hasNext())
    {
        LOG.info("selectionKeys.next()");
        Integer lookupKey = (Integer) selectionKeys.next();
        LOG.info("lookupKey = "+lookupKey);
    } else {
        LOG.info("THERE is no keys");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've figured out that for some reason, when i click a row, it's not getting set correctly. It's like it's 1 step behind my clicks. For example if i click row 1 of my datatable, my method gets into "THERE is no keys", but if i click row 2 now, my method has the keys for the first row I clicked.

Why is it 1 click behind?

Comment: What do you mean it is re-rendering before? Can you clarify how do you check that?

Comment: I'm referring to `reRender="DesignerForm:formEditToolbar"` of the a4j:support tag.

Comment: I would debug formSearch#setSelection method and check if right value is passed there as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onselectionchange` event:

```
<a4j:support event="onselectionchange" ...
```

I guess the problem with `onRowClick` is that it gets fired before selection change happen, so it submits previous selection value.

Comment: Awesome works like a charm. Was not aware of that event type.

Comment: @Catfish Great. Full set of attributes/events supported you can find for example here: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf?tab=info